# Assertions failing on Lookup relations

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a use-case where 3 custom objects are used.

Event (One) -> Meeting (Many) (Master detail)

Meeting (One) - > Attendee (Many) (Lookup)

I have built an Apex class for this.

```
public class EventManagement{

public string selected{get;set;}
public List<Selectoption> options{get;set;}
public List<Event__c> event{get;set;}
public string meets{get;set;}
public List<selectoption> opt{get;set;}
public List<Meeting__c> meeting{get;set;}
public boolean Test{get;set;}
public boolean renderTable{get;set;}
public boolean renderNew{get;set;}
public boolean imp{get;set;}
public List<AttendeesWrapper> attndWrap{get;set;}
public List<AttendeesWrapper> attndWrap2{get;set;}
public List<AttendeesWrapper> mapWrap{get;set;}
public List<Attendee__c> attList{get;set;}
public Meeting__c meetn {get;set;}
public List<Attendee__c> attList1{get;set;}

public EventManagement(){
    options=new List<selectoption>();
    event=new List<Event__c>();
    event=[select ID,Name from Event__c where   Event_Status__c = :'Approved' ];
    options.add(new selectoption('','----SELECT----'));
        for(Event__c eveList : event){
        options.add(new selectoption(eveList.ID,eveList.Name));
       }
    }


    public void mymeetings(){
    Test=true;
    opt=new List<selectoption>();
    meeting=new List<Meeting__c>();
    meeting=[select ID,Name from Meeting__c where Event__c=:selected];

    opt.add(new selectoption('','----SELECT----'));  
    for(Meeting__c mee : meeting){

        opt.add(new selectoption(mee.ID,mee.Name));
                }
    }


    public void myAttendees(){
            for(Meeting__c mt : meeting){  // Line no 52
                if(mt.name==meets)
                    meetn=mt;
            }

        attList=new List<Attendee__c>();
        attList=[Select Id,Name,Attendee_Email__c,Country__c,Status__c,Attendee__c.Meeting__c from Attendee__c where  Meeting__c=:meets];

         attndWrap = new List<AttendeesWrapper>();

         for(Attendee__c attnd : attList){
             attndWrap.add(new AttendeesWrapper(attnd));
         }

        if(attndWrap.size()>0){
             renderTable = true;


    } 
   }


   public void updateAttendee() {
        List<Attendee__c> atv = new List<Attendee__c>();

        for(AttendeesWrapper aw1 : attndWrap){
            if(aw1.selected1 == true){

            atv.add(aw1.attn1);

           }
        }

        if(atv.size()>0){
            update atv;
        }

        myAttendees();
    }


        public void newAttendee(){
         Attendee__c newA= new Attendee__c();
         attndWrap.add(new AttendeesWrapper(newA));

     }

     public void upsertAttendee(){
          List<Attendee__c> l1 = new List<Attendee__c>();
          Attendee__c atnew = attList[0];
        for(AttendeesWrapper aws: attndWrap){
            if(aws.selected1== true){
            aws.attn1.Meeting__c = atnew.Meeting__c;
                l1.add(aws.attn1);
            }
        }

        if(l1.size()>0){
            upsert l1;

        }
        myAttendees();
     }

     public void deleteAttendee(){
         List<Attendee__c> at = new List<Attendee__c>();

        for(AttendeesWrapper aw2 : attndWrap){
            if(aw2.selected1 == true){

            at.add(aw2.attn1);

           }
        }

        if(at.size()>0){
            delete at;
        }

        myAttendees();
     }

    public void importAttendee(){
        imp=true;
        List<Attendee__c> attList1 = new List<Attendee__c>();
        attList1=[select id,name,Mobile__c,Country__c,Attendee_Email__c, Attendee__c.Meeting__c from Attendee__c where Meeting__c=null];
        attndWrap2 = new List<AttendeesWrapper>();
        for(Attendee__c wa : attList1){
          attndWrap2.add(new AttendeesWrapper(wa));
        }
      } 

      public void mapAttendee(){
           List<Attendee__c> atnds = new List<Attendee__c>();
           if(meets==null){
               renderNew= false;
           }
           Attendee__c atnew = attList[0];
           for(AttendeesWrapper atL : attndWrap2){

                 if(atL.selected1 == true){
                    Attendee__c atn4 = atL.attn1;
                    atn4.Meeting__c=atnew.Meeting__c ;
                    atnds.add(atn4);
                 }
          }
          upsert atnds;
          myAttendees();
          imp=false;
        }




    /* Wrapper Class */

       public class AttendeesWrapper {
         public Attendee__c attn1 {get;set;}
         public boolean selected1{get;set;}

         public AttendeesWrapper(Attendee__c ab) {
             this.attn1=ab;
             this.selected1=false;

         }
       }  
}
```

This is my test class:

```
    @isTest
public class TestProject{

     static testmethod void test_Eventcontroller(){

        /* Creating Event Records */


        Event__c evnt = new Event__c(name='TestEvent', Event_Status__c='Approved');
        insert evnt;
        Event__c evnt1 = new Event__c(name='TestEvent1', Event_Status__c='Approved');
        insert evnt1;
        EventManagement aoc= new EventManagement();
        System.assertEquals(2,aoc.event.size());

    }

    static testmethod void test_Meeting(){

       EventManagement aoc= new EventManagement();
     Event__c event = new Event__c(name='TestEvent', Event_Status__c='Approved');
        insert event;

       Event__c evnt1 = new Event__c(name='TestEvent1', Event_Status__c='Approved');
        insert evnt1;

    Meeting__c mtn = new Meeting__c(name='TestMeeting',Event__c=evnt1.id);
        insert mtn;

        aoc.selected = evnt1.id; //the line to add

        aoc.mymeetings();
        //Test.StartTest(); 
        System.assertEquals(1,aoc.meeting.size());
        //Test.StopTest();
    }

    static testmethod void test_Attendees(){
         EventManagement aoc= new EventManagement();
        Event__c evnt1 = new Event__c(name='TestEvent1', Event_Status__c='Approved');
        insert evnt1;
        Meeting__c mtn = new Meeting__c(name='TestMeeting',Event__c=evnt1.id);
        insert mtn;
        Attendee__c att = new Attendee__c(name='Test Attendee',Meeting__c=mtn.id);
        insert att;
        System.debug('mtnmmmmmmmmmmm :'+mtn);
        System.debug('aoccccccccccc :'+aoc);
         aoc.meets = mtn.id; //the line to add
         aoc.mymeetings();
         aoc.myAttendees(); // Line no 56
        //Test.StartTest();
        System.assertEquals(1,aoc.attndWrap.size());
        //Test.StopTest();
    }   
}
```

Attendees assertion is only failing after modification.

Expected 1. Found 0

Answer (score 1):

For your `test_Meeting` method, you forgot to set the `selected` variable on your controller before calling the `mymeetings` method.

Here's the right code:

```
static testmethod void test_Meeting(){

       EventManagement aoc= new EventManagement();
     Event__c event = new Event__c(name='TestEvent', Event_Status__c='Approved');
        insert event;

       Event__c evnt1 = new Event__c(name='TestEvent1', Event_Status__c='Approved');
        insert evnt1;

    Meeting__c mtn = new Meeting__c(name='TestMeeting',Event__c=evnt1.id);
        insert mtn;

        aoc.selected = evnt1.id; //the line to add

        aoc.mymeetings();
        //Test.StartTest(); 
        System.assertEquals(1,aoc.meeting.size());
        //Test.StopTest();
    }
```

For your third method, you have to insert your records before calling the controller methods. You have also to set the `selected` and `meets` variables of the controller.

Here's the correction:

```
static testmethod void test_Attendees(){
         EventManagement aoc= new EventManagement();
        Event__c evnt1 = new Event__c(name='TestEvent1', Event_Status__c='Approved');
        insert evnt1;
        Meeting__c mtn = new Meeting__c(name='TestMeeting',Event__c=evnt1.id);
        insert mtn;
        Attendee__c att = new Attendee__c(name='Test Attendee',Meeting__c=mtn.id);
        insert att;

         aoc.meets = mtn.id; //the line to add

         aoc.myAttendees();
        //Test.StartTest();
        System.assertEquals(1,aoc.attndWrap.size());
        //Test.StopTest();
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou, test_Meeting() is working now, but test_Attendees() is still failing. Assertion error. Expected 1. Found 0

Comment: Are you sure you added the line: `aoc.meets = mtn.id;` before calling the `myAttendees` method?

Comment: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object at this line: aoc.meets = mtn.id; //the line to add

Comment: Did you copy my whole test method for `test_Attendees`?

Comment: Updated the question with latest code

Comment: I really don't understand how this is possible to have a **Attempt to de-reference a null object** message on this line. Can you debug to see what is null?

Comment: Updated. Please check